# AWS DOCKER dm.basesize in /etc/sysconfig/docker doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I want to change dm.basesize in my containers .

These are the size of containers to 20GB

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
`-xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk 
xvdg    202:96   0   8G  0 disk
```

I have  a sh

```
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash

cloud-init-per once docker_options echo 'OPTIONS="${OPTIONS} --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker
~
```

I executed this script

I stopped the docker service

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-55 ~]$ sudo service docker stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop docker.service
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-55 ~]$
```

I started docker service

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-55 ~]$ sudo service docker start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start docker.service
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-55 ~]$
```

But the container size doesn't change.

This is /etc/sysconfig/docker file

```
#The max number of open files for the daemon itself, and all
# running containers.  The default value of 1048576 mirrors the value
# used by the systemd service unit.
DAEMON_MAXFILES=1048576

# Additional startup options for the Docker daemon, for example:
# OPTIONS="--ip-forward=true --iptables=true"
# By default we limit the number of open files per container
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"

# How many seconds the sysvinit script waits for the pidfile to appear
# when starting the daemon.
DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT=10
```

I read  in the aws documentation that I can to execute scripts in the aws instance when I start it . I don't want to restart my aws instance because I lost my data.

Is there a way to  update my container size without restart the aws instance?

In the aws documentation I don't find how to set a script when I launch the aws instance.

I follow the tutorial

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html
```

I don't find a example how to set a script when I launch the aws instance.

UPDATED

I configured the file 
/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
    {
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
  "storage-opts": [
    "dm.directlvm_device=/dev/xdf",
    "dm.thinp_percent=95",
    "dm.thinp_metapercent=1",
    "dm.thinp_autoextend_threshold=80",
    "dm.thinp_autoextend_percent=20",
    "dm.directlvm_device_force=false"
  ]
}
```

When I start docker, I get

```
 Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: /dev/xdf is not available for use with devicemapper
```

How can I configure the parameter

```
dm.directlvm_device=/dev/xdf
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `devicemapper` Docker storage driver, and not something newer like `overlay2`?  Unless you're using `devicemapper` the setting you're trying to change won't have an effect.

Comment: The `df` output you're showing is properties of the EC2 instance itself.  It's nothing Docker-specific, and there aren't boot-time options that affect it.  You need to provision a new larger EBS volume and attach it to the instance; it's probably easiest to do this when first starting the instance.

Comment: Finally you should be aware that AWS does occasionally just arbitrary terminate EC2 instances and this is totally outside your control.  You need to be prepared to recreate your setup on a new system.

Comment: I update my question